# Fetching multiple occurences of text in shell

Tags: linux, shell

I have a file like:

HEADING-1

abc

def

ghi

END

HEADING-2

uvw

xyz

END

Now, i want all text between HEADING- and END for every occurence. How can i do that? I tried using grep and sed but it came only for single occurence. I want this output in separate files for each HEADING- and END occurence

Comment: Where/how do you want the results stored or shown? And please show the exact code you tried.

Comment: this? `sed -n '/^HEADING/,/^END/p' input`

Answer (score 0):

This will write each occurrence of HEADING-to-END to a separate file:

```
$ awk '/HEADING/{f="file" ++i} /HEADING/,/END/{print>f}' file
```

After running the above with the sample data, there will be two new files in the directory:

```
$ cat file1
HEADING-1
abc
def
ghi
END
```

And:

```
$ cat file2
HEADING-2
uvw
xyz
END
```

#### How it works

- `/HEADING/{f="file" ++i}`

  Every time we reach a line that contains HEADING, this updates the variable `f` to contain a new file name.
- `/HEADING/,/END/{print>f}`

  For any line in a range of lines that starts with `HEADING` and ends with `END`, this writes that line to file `f`.

#### Variation: exclude the HEADING and END lines

With a minor change to the code, we can write the same except that the HEADING and END lines are omitted:

```
$ awk '/END/{f=""} f{print>f} /HEADING/{f="file" ++i}' file
$ cat file1
abc
def
ghi
$ cat file2
uvw
xyz
```

Answer (score 0):

There are a large number of ways to approach this. If you simply want the lines with text between each `HEADING*` and `END` separated into separate files, (e.g. `file_000.txt, file_001.txt, ...` you can simply use a `while` loop and use `expr` to check the contents of each line and either skip, increment the file count, or write the line to the current `filecnt` numbered file. For example:

```
#!/bin/sh

fn="${1:-/dev/stdin}"   ## input filename (or stdin, default)

[ -r "$1" ] || {        ## check that file is readable
    printf "error: file not readable '%s'\n" "$fn"
    exit 1
}

declare -i filecnt=0    ## counter for file number

while IFS= read -r line; do  ## read each line
    if [ $(expr "$line" : "HEADING.*") -gt 0 ]  ## skip if HEADING*
    then
        continue
    elif [ $(expr "$line" : "END.*") -gt 0 ]    ## skip + inc filecnt on END
    then
        ((filecnt++))
        continue
    elif [ $(expr length "$line") -gt 0 ]       ## test non-blank line
    then
        printf -v ofn "file_%03d.txt" "$filecnt"  ## set output file name
        printf "$line\n" >> "$ofn"                ## write line to file name
    fi
done <"$fn"
```

**Input File**

```
$ cat dat/he.txt
HEADING-1

abc

def

ghi

END

HEADING-2

uvw

xyz

END
```

**Example Use/Output Files**

```
$ sh hdg2end.sh dat/he.txt

$ cat file_000.txt
abc
def
ghi

$ cat file_001.txt
uvw
xyz
```

Look things over and let me know if you have any questions. (note: depending on your version of `read` you may or may not have the `-r` option -- if not, just omit it)